# Output a single base css class to specify background-image

Tags: css, css-sprites, grunt-spritesmith

I am using `grunt-spritesmith` and it generates a css file such as this:

```
.icon-admin {
  background-image: url(../sprites/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -288px -856px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-report {
  background-image: url(../sprites/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -256px -888px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

This works fine. What I want to do is to use a base css class for icons for specifying the `background-image` (like what Compass does), so the output is like this:

```
.icon {
  background-image: url(../sprites/spritesheet.png);
}
.icon-admin {
  background-position: -288px -856px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-report {
  background-position: -256px -888px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

I wonder if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `cssTemplate` function ([example](https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith#template-function)).
A quick (and dirty) implementation would be ([based on this](https://github.com/twolfson/spritesheet-templates/blob/4.2.0/lib/templates/css.template.js)):

```
cssTemplate: function(params) {
  var fs = require('fs'),
    mustache = require('mustache'),
    tmpl = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/template/css.template.mustache', 'utf8'),
    items = params.items,
    options = params.options;

  // Fallback class naming function
  var classFn = options.cssClass || function defaultCssClass (item) {
        return '.icon-' + item.name;
      };

  // Add class to each of the options
  items.forEach(function saveClass (item) {
    item['class'] = classFn(item);
  });
  // Set the default class
  options.cssClass = options.cssClass || '.icon';

  // Render and return CSS
  var css = mustache.render(tmpl, params);
  return css;
}
```

Also, you need this template (placed inside a `template` directory, [based on this](https://github.com/twolfson/spritesheet-templates/blob/4.2.0/lib/templates/css.template.mustache)):

```
{{options.cssClass}} {
  background-image: url({{{spritesheet.escaped_image}}});
}

{{#items}}
{{class}} {
  background-position: {{px.offset_x}} {{px.offset_y}};
  width: {{px.width}};
  height: {{px.height}};
}
{{/items}}
```

This should do the trick.